# how to modify colors.xml in android app,then i can change my theme's color

Tags: java, android, eclipse, colors, themes

I want to change some attributes in colors.xml file in my android app, then i can get a new theme's color.I just don't know how to change colors.xml file. Thank you.[PS:English is not my mother tongue, so...]

Answer (score 1):

You can change(edit) existing colors in `/res/values/colors.xml` and create new colors as you need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#009688</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00796B</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryLight">#B2DFDB</color>
    <color name="textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="windowBackground">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="navigationBarColor">#000000</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#4CAF50</color>
    <color name="colorSecondaryText">#727272</color>
    <color name="divider">#B6B6B6</color>
</resources>
```

You can use and customize your theme in `/res/values/styles.xml`. Notice the values set for the color resources in `colors.xml` is used in `styles.xml` to customize the theme.

```
<resources>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

    </style>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="Widget.CardContent" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">24dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">24dp</item>
        <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And you apply your theme to the activities in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.ThirdActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_book_store"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" />
```

For more info, see this post by [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/)

Comment: When my app run, there is a button which let customers to select a color to show on primarycolordack, colorprimary, or colorAccent. How to do that? Anything, thank you@jayeshsolanki93 @Htoo Aung Hlaing

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your theame from res>values>styles.xml in values folder  .

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateHidden|adjustPan</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: When my app run, there is a button or something which let customers to select a color to show on primarycolordack, colorprimary, or colorAccent. How to do that? Anything, thank you. @Jinal Patel